Ethernet not working after upgradin to 24.04
In recently updated my ThinlPad-T470p from 22.04 to 24.04. 
Update went smoothly, except for the fact that afterwards Ethernet ceased to work (cat6 and USB3.0), Wifi works well.
Outputs are:
~$sudo lsusb
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp. Bluetooth wireless interface
Bus 001 Device 010: ID 04f2:b5c0 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd Integrated Camera
Bus 001 Device 012: ID 058f:9540 Alcor Micro Corp. AU9540 Smartcard Reader
Bus 001 Device 043: ID 138a:0097 Validity Sensors, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 044: ID 1199:9079 Sierra Wireless, Inc. EM7455
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub

~$ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s31f6: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 54:e1:ad:5a:f6:bc brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether ac:ed:5c:5f:e6:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.136/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp3s0
       valid_lft 3382sec preferred_lft 3382sec
    inet6 2a00:a041:e03a:c200:3adf:157e:c5dd:65ce/64 scope global temporary dynamic 
       valid_lft 300sec preferred_lft 300sec
    inet6 2a00:a041:e03a:c200:ab08:c7c7:f08f:4afa/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 300sec preferred_lft 300sec
    inet6 fe80::11b0:f4cb:5946:bc6b/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
13: wwan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,NOARP> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 26:7a:ce:f3:f4:52 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
14: enxe04f435c57e3: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether e0:4f:43:5c:57:e3 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

Ask if there are any other things to check.
